# Error is syntax of sql when updating item

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to edit an item, but i keep getting the error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use.

I've searched on google what the problem with my syntax is, but i can't see the problem.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['ga']) ) {
        $artikel = new artikel();

        $artikel->id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $artikel->artNaam = $_POST['naam'];
        $artikel->artOmschrijving = $_POST['oms'];
        $artikel->artOmsKort = $_POST['omsKort'];
        $artikel->artPrijs = $_POST['prijs'];
        $artikel->artCategorie = $_POST['categorie'];

        $sql = "update items set 
            artNaam='$artikel->artNaam', 
            artOmschrijving='$artikel->artOmschrijving', 
            artOmsKort='$artikel->artOmsKort', 
            artPrijs=$artikel->artPrijs, 
            artCategorie='$artikel->artCategorie' 
            where id=$artikel->id";

        if ( $conn->query($sql) ) {
            header('Location: wijzigArtikel.php?'.$artikel->id);                    
        } else {
            die($conn->error);
        }

        unset($_SESSION['id']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest way to debug, and help us help you, be to print the final $sql string?

Comment: How about `addslashes()`? Topic: mysql-sql-injection.

Comment: It's amazing how much easier it is to work with bind variables in prepared statements, and equally amazing how so many of these problems simply cease to be issues when you do so

Comment: The full error will give you the snippet of SQL with the syntax error - please ad that to your question

Comment: There was indeed a qoute and the addslashes worked! Thanks!

Comment: Don't use addslashes. If you're not going to use a prepared statement, use `$conn->real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a quote in one of the string values. Since you're using mysqli, you should use a prepared statement instead of substituting variables.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("update items set 
        artNaam=?, 
        artOmschrijving=?, 
        artOmsKort=?, 
        artPrijs=?, 
        artCategorie=? 
        where id=?";
$stmt->bind_param("sssisi", $artikel->artNaam, $artikel->artOmschriving,
            $artikel->artOmsKort, $artikel->artPrijs, $artikel->artCategorie,
            $artikel->id);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    header('Location: wijzigArtikel.php?'.$artikel->id);                    
} else {
    die($conn->error);
}

unset($_SESSION['id']);
```

Comment: The was indeed a quote in there. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead :

```
 $sql = "update items set 
            artNaam='".$artikel->artNaam."', 
            artOmschrijving='".$artikel->artOmschrijving."', 
            artOmsKort='".$artikel->artOmsKort."', 
            artPrijs=$artikel->artPrijs, 
            artCategorie='".$artikel->artCategorie,"' 
            where id=$artikel->id";
```

Variables in string cant be in single quotes, single quotes only will write $artikel->artNaam istead of the value.

Comment: Single quotes inside the string don't prevent variable substitution. It juset matters whether the string begins with single or double quote.

Comment: If the string is surrounded in double quotes, single quotes within it do not stop variable substitution